# Python 3.X write dictionary from list to file

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a list like this:

```
d = [{string1:float1,string2: float2},{string1:float3,string2:float4},...]
```

I tried:

```
import json
with open("outputfile.txt","w") as f:
    json.dump(d,f)
```

then all the content is in one line like:

```
[{string1:float1,string2: float2},{string1:float3,string2:float4},{string1:float5,string2:float6},...]
```

what I want is for each (key:valve) starts a newline,like

```
[{string1:float1,
string2:float2},
{string1:float3,
string2:float4},
...
endstring:endfloat}]
```

how can I do this ? or I can just replace every "," to ",\n"? The order does not matter much, but if possible, a "sorted" result will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/json.html:

```
json.dumps({'4': 5, '6': 7}, sort_keys=True, indent=4, separators=(',', ': '))
```

should result in:

```
{
    "4": 5,
    "6": 7
}
```

Python 3.x solution is identical.

Note the use of dumps as opposed to dump.

Updated solution:

```
for dict in d:
    with open("outputfile.txt","a") as f:
        json.dump(dict, f)
        f.write('\n')
```

or

```
for dict in d:
    with open("outputfile.txt","a") as f:
        json.dump(dict, f, indent=4)
```

Comment: I tried:`for item in d:
 json.dumps(item,sort_keys = True,indent=4, separators=(',', ': '))
 with open("output.txt","w") as i:
  json.dump(item,i)`
and it does not work...still in the same line

Comment: open("output.txt","w") will overwrite the same line repeatedly, you need to use open("output.txt","a") to append.

Comment: I just tested this using the python shell and got this: `'{\n "4": 5,\n "6": 7\n}'`  As you can see, json.dumps has created a string for me, so you don't need to loop through it or anything, just `x = json.dumps(...)` then `file.write(x)` or similar.

Comment: `'{\n "4": 5,\n "6": 7\n}'` is not `'{"4": 5,(stars a new line)"6": 7}'` in your solution, '\n' is treated as string not 'new line'

Comment: Updated solution.

Comment: the first updated solution looks better. btw, I prefer some other notation than 'dict' .thx anyway.